# How to download the entire or a subset of whois database offline for analysis

Tags: whois

I have a work project where I need to perform analysis on domain registrants behind a whois guard/proxy and figure out who they are(they are mostly bad guys who use domains for malware).
As a demonstration, if I run a whois lookup on test.com(I will not use a malicious domain here for obvious reason)

```
whois test.com -h whois.networksolutions.com
```

I get the following result:

```
[Querying whois.networksolutions.com]
[whois.networksolutions.com]
Domain Name: TEST.COM
Registry Domain ID: 5429075_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.networksolutions.com
Registrar URL: http://networksolutions.com
Updated Date: 2018-07-21T07:22:47Z
Creation Date: 1997-06-18T04:00:00Z
Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 2019-06-17T04:00:00Z
Registrar: NETWORK SOLUTIONS, LLC.
Registrar IANA ID: 2
Reseller: 
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
Registry Registrant ID: 
Registrant Name: PERFECT PRIVACY, LLC
Registrant Organization: 
Registrant Street: 12808 Gran Bay Parkway West
Registrant City: Jacksonville
Registrant State/Province: FL
Registrant Postal Code: 32258
Registrant Country: US
Registrant Phone: +1.5707088780
Registrant Phone Ext: 
Registrant Fax: 
Registrant Fax Ext: 
Registrant Email: qq9tq6x63es@networksolutionsprivateregistration.com
Registry Admin ID: 
Admin Name: PERFECT PRIVACY, LLC
Admin Organization: 
Admin Street: 12808 Gran Bay Parkway West
Admin City: Jacksonville
Admin State/Province: FL
Admin Postal Code: 32258
Admin Country: US
Admin Phone: +1.5707088780
Admin Phone Ext: 
Admin Fax: 
Admin Fax Ext: 
Admin Email: qq9tq6x63es@networksolutionsprivateregistration.com
Registry Tech ID: 
Tech Name: PERFECT PRIVACY, LLC
Tech Organization: 
Tech Street: 12808 Gran Bay Parkway West
Tech City: Jacksonville
Tech State/Province: FL
Tech Postal Code: 32258
Tech Country: US
Tech Phone: +1.5707088780
Tech Phone Ext: 
Tech Fax: 
Tech Fax Ext: 
Tech Email: t96nb4x48wg@networksolutionsprivateregistration.com
Name Server: NS65.WORLDNIC.COM
Name Server: NS66.WORLDNIC.COM
DNSSEC: unsigned
Registrar Abuse Contact Email: abuse@web.com
Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1.8003337680
URL of the ICANN WHOIS Data Problem Reporting System: http://wdprs.internic.net/
>>> Last update of WHOIS database: 2018-10-17T23:18:12Z <<<]
```

You will see that it's behind a whois proxy.  In order to figure out the real registrant behind this domain, I need to access all the domains in aggregate and run my model on it.   However, most whois servers quickly throttle me if I perform the lookup repeatedly.
Is there a way to get around this?  Or better yet to have a full access to the entire set of domains names with whois records?    how would I request such access?

Comment: "I have a work project where I need to perform analysis on domain registrants behind a whois guard/proxy"  if they are behind a proxy there is probably a reason so how could you imagine that, for "anyone"  it would be possible to bypass that and get the true registrant? Don't you think it voids the whole proxy feature?

Comment: @Patrick Mevzek: there's no direct way to by pass whois proxy.  You can guess based on historic data, but it's not a sure way.